# Django saves as Object (1) instead of value?

Tags: django

Am using ModelChoiceField in form and trying to save the form but it saves as Object (1) and Object (2) instead of data name.

I know that i can change that by adding

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.name
```

to the model, but i dont want to change this as its connected with other things. Is there any other way to attain this without adding **str** to model ?

```
My model:
class TrendingCourse(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    course_slug = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

And my form:

```
class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name


class CourseForm(ModelForm):

    course_slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput({'class': 'form-control'}), required=False)

    course = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.filter(owner_id=2), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-select', 'data-placeholder':'Select any trending course'}))

    class Meta:
        model = TrendingCourse
        fields = [ 'course', 'course_slug' ]
```

Comment: Can you show your form and model? Sounds like you are using a `forms.ModelChoiceField` to populate a `models.CharField`, why not use a ForeignKey?

Comment: Even using `__str__` would *not* solve the "real" issue: you should *not* use a `CharField` to store a reference to an item.

Comment: Interesting, can i know why is that @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: I have updated form and model @IainShelvington

Comment: @yoknamitru: imagine that you rename the `Course`, then how is your `TrendingCourse` supposed to find the (renamed) `Course`?

Comment: Okay, kinda understood ! @WillemVanOnsem so how address this issue ?

Comment: And am just storing this course thing for reference purpose, it doesnt have any value though !!

Comment: Converting Char to Foreign key would solve this problem ? How the data would be stored as still i am not gonna use __str__ @WillemVanOnsem